# Prevent From Writing on TextArea using Bind Event "input propertychange"

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, textarea, disabled-input

I am handling the content inside a textarea using binding a function to the event "input propertychange"

Like this:

```
$('#textarea').bind('input propertychange', function () {    
    var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');    
    window.lastLineWriting = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.value.length).split("\n").length;                    
    var writingOnLine = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;                  
    if (writingOnLine < window.lastLineWriting) {
        //dont write on textarea
    }
});
```

I don't know how to prevent the char typed by the user's keyboard to appear on the textarea... Inside that if I want to prevent the text to be inserted on textarea..
How can I do this?

Comment: What do you want to print on text-area ?

Comment: What do you mean ? Inside that If () {} I want to disable the text to be inserted on textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could easily stop the user from typing with this code, using jQuery:

```
$('textarea').bind('keypress', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

**NOTE:**

this code will prevent the user from typing in all the textareas, to bind it specifically to one or some selected elements, you must change the selector to the desired elements.

Comment: You are my saviour :D Thanks alot ! Solved !

Comment: By the way, how can I change the text of the textarea inside the function I bind to the event keypress? I am using something like this:

textarea.value = textarea.value + "testing..";  but its not working, the textarea doesn't change text

Comment: you have to use `$(this).val($(this).val()+'testing...');` but only if you're using it inside the keypress function.

Comment: Well I used like this:  var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
                 textarea.value = textarea.value + "\nCommand>";  and worked now :D  thanks anyway !

Answer (score 0):

```
 var editable = false // Your Condition
    if(editable != "true"){
        $("#textarea" ).attr("disabled",true);
     }
```